# ListGroup two link

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```css
 .btn {
                      box-shadow: none !important;
                      outline: 0;
                    }
    
                    .list-group-item span {
                      border: solid #222;
                      border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
                      display: inline;
                      cursor: pointer;
                      padding: 3px;
                      position: absolute;
                      right: 0;
                      margin-top: 10px;
                    }
    
                    .list-group-item a.btn.collapsed span {
                      transform: rotate(40deg);
                      -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
                      transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
                    }
    
                    .list-group-item a.btn span {
                      transform: rotate(-140deg);
                      -webkit-transform: rotate(-140deg);
                      transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
                    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="my-5">
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    
                <li class="list-group-item px-0">
                  <a class="btn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample1">
                Link with href<span class="mr-3"></span>
                </a>
                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample1">
                    <div class="card card-body mt-2">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
    
                <li class="list-group-item px-0">
                  <a class="btn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
                Link with href<span class="mr-3"></span>
                </a>
                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
                    <div class="card card-body mt-2">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
    
                <li class="list-group-item px-0">
                  <a class="btn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample3">
                Link with href<span class="mr-3"></span>
                </a>
                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
                    <div class="card card-body mt-2">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
    
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

How could I put an additional link to another page in the text: Link with href?

```
<li class="list-group-item px-0"> <a class="btn collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample3" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample3"> <a href="someURL">Link with href</a> <span class="mr-3"></span> </a>
```

It doesn't work. I need that within li, have the link in the "arrow" to show the div
for more information, but that where it says the text Link with href,
have another link, to another page. In the example I tried it doesn't work, because it's all decentralized and if I have to put two  it disconfigures the layout

Comment: Can you correct your html and css code? The code example above seems to be broken.

Comment: Now, try again!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is illegal in HTML5 to nest an anchor tag inside another anchor tag. It's not 100% clear what you're trying to accomplish with the layout. It may help to provide mockups or wireframes.

Just to show you that it's possible, you can use positioning to give the illusion that one anchor is nested inside another. Here's an example:

CSS

```
li {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
  list-style: none;
}
.big {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
  height: 70px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.small {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 10px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<li>
<a href="google.com" class="big">Big anchor</a>
<a href="facebook.com" class="small">Small anchor</a>
</li>
```

You can view a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/j0eq6bxr/14/

Again, I can probably give you something closer to what you're looking for if you provide some visual examples of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. But I Need in the same line